# Include a rich calendar in JSF

Tags: jsf, calendar, richfaces

Can anyone helpme how to create a rich calendar in JSF.The sample project created using maven

Following is my code

default.xhtml

```
<rich:calendar id="dtDOB" 
  datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd" required="true" 
  label="startcalender"  >
</rich:calendar>
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://richfaces.org/rich declared
with prefix rich but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.
```

I know I have to missed somthing in web.xml file.
Weather I have to add some `<dependency>` in the pom.xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have not added Richfaces libraries in your project .
GO 
http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/GettingStarted.html

Comment: Please note that RichFaces 3.x is outdated and that OP seems to use JSF 2.x for which you should be using RichFaces 4.x instead. So that RichFaces 3.x link is actually wrong.